# Sharepoint 2010: Deployment is not reflected remotely

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have VS 2010 installed on the same VM machine as my sharepoint 2010 server that I remote into. When I create a simple webpart and click "run", it appears to compile and deploy the webpart with no problems, and opens up http://[sharepointserver]/SitePages/Home.aspx.

In the demos I have seen, I expected to see my webpart page.  So, I click on "edit" > "Insert" > "web part" > "custom" > choose my webpart.

Then my http://[sharepointserver]/SitePages/Home.aspx shows the webpart.

HOWEVER,

When I access that same url from my local machine (not remoted into the VM), I don't see the weppart on that page at all.  I click refresh, and the webpart debugger indicates webpart pass-through activity, but the page is the standard "welcome to your site!" page.

Do I need to explicitly "deploy" this?  It's confusing since they are the same url, being accessed from two different contexts (browsers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you edited the page and added your web part, did you save it and check it in?